# Parsing int or float with FParsec

Tags: f#, fparsec

I'm trying to parse a file, using FParsec, which consists of either float or int values. I'm facing two problems that I can't find a good solution for.

**1**

Both `pint32` and `pfloat` will successfully parse the same string, but give different answers, e.g `pint32` will return `3` when parsing the string `"3.0"` and `pfloat` will return `3.0` when parsing the same string. Is it possible to try parsing a floating point value using `pint32` and have it fail if the string is `"3.0"`?

In other words, is there a way to make the following code work:

```
let parseFloatOrInt lines =
    let rec loop intvalues floatvalues lines =
        match lines with
        | [] -> floatvalues, intvalues
        | line::rest ->
            match run floatWs line with
            | Success (r, _, _) -> loop intvalues (r::floatvalues) rest
            | Failure _ -> 
                match run intWs line with
                | Success (r, _, _) -> loop (r::intvalues) floatvalues rest
                | Failure _ -> loop intvalues floatvalues rest

    loop [] [] lines
```

This piece of code will correctly place all floating point values in the `floatvalues` list, but because `pfloat` returns `"3.0"` when parsing the string `"3"`, all integer values will also be placed in the `floatvalues` list.

**2**

The above code example seems a bit clumsy to me, so I'm guessing there must be a better way to do it. I considered combining them using `choice`, however both parsers  must return the same type for that to work. I guess I could make a discriminated union with one option for float and one for int and convert the output from `pint32` and `pfloat` using the `|>>` operator. However, I'm wondering if there is a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right path thinking about defining domain data and separating *definition* of parsers and their *usage* on source data. This seems to be a good approach, because as your real-life project grows further, you would probably need more data types.

Here's how I would write it:

```
/// The resulting type, or DSL
type MyData =
    | IntValue of int
    | FloatValue of float
    | Error  // special case for all parse failures

// Then, let's define individual parsers:
let pMyInt =
    pint32
    |>> IntValue

// this is an alternative version of float parser.
// it ensures that the value has non-zero fractional part.
// caveat: the naive approach would treat values like 42.0 as integer
let pMyFloat =
    pfloat
    >>= (fun x -> if x % 1 = 0 then fail "Not a float" else preturn (FloatValue x))
let pError =
    // this parser must consume some input,
    // otherwise combined with `many` it would hang in a dead loop
    skipAnyChar
    >>. preturn Error

 // Now, the combined parser:
let pCombined =
    [ pMyFloat; pMyInt; pError ]    // note, future parsers will be added here;
                                    // mind the order as float supersedes the int,
                                    // and Error must be the last
    |> List.map (fun p -> p .>> ws) // I'm too lazy to add whitespase skipping
                                    // into each individual parser
    |> List.map attempt             // each parser is optional
    |> choice                       // on each iteration, one of the parsers must succeed
    |> many                         // a loop
```

Note, the code above is capable working with any sources: strings, streams, or whatever. Your real app may need to work with files, but unit testing can be simplified by using just `string list`.

```
// Now, applying the parser somewhere in the code:
let maybeParseResult =
    match run pCombined myStringData with
    | Success(result, _, _) -> Some result
    | Failure(_, _, _)      -> None // or anything that indicates general parse failure
```

UPD. I have edited the code according to comments. `pMyFloat` was updated to ensure that the parsed value has non-zero fractional part.

Comment: By the way @bytebuster, I'm having some trouble running the pCombined on a test string, it gives the error message ``The combinator 'many' was applied to a parser that succeeds without consuming input and without changing the parser state in any other way.``. Does eof neeed to be handled?

Comment: Great, thanks @bytebuster! One more thing, I tried running the parser on the string `"2 "` after I had removed the `many` combinator, and then I got the same problem as I described above, namely that it was returned as a float because the float parser comes before the int parser. Any ideas on how to remedy that?

Comment: @Chepe, Please check the updated version. Hopefully, it addresses both issues.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: FYI; backtrack (ie `attempt`) can be an expensive operation which is why I believe FParsec chose to make backtracking explicit.

Answer (score 2):

**FParsec** has the [`numberLiteral`](https://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/charparsers.html#members.numberLiteral) parser that can be used to solve the problem.

As a start you can use the example available at the link above:

```ml
open FParsec
open FParsec.Primitives
open FParsec.CharParsers

type Number = Int   of int64
            | Float of float

                    // -?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?
let numberFormat =     NumberLiteralOptions.AllowMinusSign
                   ||| NumberLiteralOptions.AllowFraction
                   ||| NumberLiteralOptions.AllowExponent

let pnumber : Parser<Number, unit> =
    numberLiteral numberFormat "number"
    |>> fun nl ->
            if nl.IsInteger then Int (int64 nl.String)
            else Float (float nl.String)
```