# Backward compatibility on parsing by means of FParsec

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

Imagine that I have simple string (in reality this string can contains much complex items like digit combination, Guid etc...):
"a, b, c"
and appropriate parser which works great with it.

Then after some changes string becomes:
"a, b, c, d, e"
Parser has been rewritten in manner to aim successful result.

But now I have to be sure that rewritten parser doesn't fail on parsing old format string.
Is it possible to provide backward compatibility with FParsec?

Comment: Unit tests perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

The backward compatibility should be implemented within your data model, and make the parser only to support this data model.

Say, if your `Result` datatype is a `List<>` (which is intended to be 3-elemens long), only a minimal intrusion makes the parser return a 4-element data. You then check data validity with your application logic, and you're all set.

However, if your `Result` is a fixed tuple/triple like `T1 * T2 * T3`, there is no straightforward way to add the fourth element. You would probably need an extra layer — usually implemented as a Discriminated Union (DU), like this:

```
type MyData = 
  | OldFormat of T1 * T2 * T3       // this is your old way
  | NewFormat of T1 * T2 * T3 * T4  // this is your new data format
```

This way, you will have to implement a wrapper DU and also duplicate the parsing logic to support the 4-element data.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31948386/974789), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20020840/974789), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35176361/974789) answers for some simple ways of parsing the "list of either-either" data.

Unless you provide with the existing code, it is hard to tell anything further.